# Sending email with .SendObject Adds Extra line break at the beginning

Tags: vba, email, ms-access, line-breaks

When I use DoCmd.SendObject on a report with the option to edit the message prior to sending, it always includes an additional linebreak at the very beginning of the message.  Any way to remove this line?

I've reference Stack Overflow for years, through my Bachelor's and Master's, and now in the professional world, but I just made an account and this is my first post.  Super excited to finally collaborate :)

Anyway, here is the code I've been using:

```
Dim sExistingReportName As String
Dim sAttachmentName As String
Dim accEmail As String
Dim accName As String

DoCmd.Requery rptAccountingRep
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptAccountingRep", acViewReport, "", "", acHidden
accEmail = [Reports]![rptAccountingRep]![strEMail]
accName = [Reports]![rptAccountingRep]![First Name]

sExistingReportName = "rptClaimFormToPrint_Invoice"
sAttachmentName = "Claim " & [Reports]![rptClaimFormToPrint_Invoice]![tblClaimForm_strClaim]

Reports(sExistingReportName).Caption = sAttachmentName

DoCmd.SendObject acReport, "rptClaimFormToPrint_Invoice", "PDFFormat(*.pdf)", accEmail, "", "", "Claim to Process -" & [Reports]![rptClaimFormToPrint_Invoice]![tblClaimForm_strClaim], "Hi " & accName & "," & vbNewLine & "Attached is a new claim to process.  Let me know if you have any questions!", True, ""
DoCmd.Close acReport, "rptAccountingRep"
```

Comment: So it's right before `Hi` ?

Comment: Correct.  The message body begins with the line break, then does "Hi [whomever]," on the next line.

Comment: You're likely at the will of `SendObject` then. --- you can `OutputTo` and then use another mail option like `Outlook.MailItem` or `CDO.Message` and attach the saved object to the email manually.

Comment: Great suggestion, thanks!